# Docker Swarm to encrypt password in application.properties as docker-compose?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

In a Spring Boot app, I am just trying to encrypt passwords used in the `docker-compose.yml` and `application.properties.yml` files. But I am not sure if `Docker Swarm` is a proper option for me because I share the app with the customer who will run the app via the commands that I provide (e.g. docker-compose using Dockerfile in the project).

So, my questions are:

**1.** Is `Docker Swarm` is a proper option for me to encrypt password in `docker-compose.yml` and `application.properties.yml` files?

**2.** How can I encrypt the passwords, can you basically explain some steps?

Comment: I think of Swarm as more of a cluster-based container engine than a password store.

Comment: Does anybody else have never encrypt passwords, etc. in the docker-compose.yml and application.properties.yml files?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for reply. Actually my purpose it to encrypt passwords in docker-compose.yml and application.properties.yml files rather than storing. So, is it a proper choice for my situation? Or what would you suggest?

Comment: If you have multiple hosts and you have a specific reason to not use Kubernetes then you could consider it.

Comment: I don't have neither Kubernetes nor multiple host. My purpose is only hiding secrets used in docker-compose.yml and application.properties.yml files on **PRODUCTION** environment. While sharing code with customer, I want to hide passwords on these files and let the customer to run the app by using a private key or any specific command.

Comment: In this case, should I use something like Jasypt? But it does not work properly giving error. Any idea?